# Junk character getting printed in PDF when I use left-to-right embedding

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I was facing an issue while trying to print a string in right-to-left alignment - for eg. doc* gets printed as *doc. To resolve this issue I've added LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING \u202A and it started printing properly.
But the usage of this character gives another issue - it prints a junk character in pdf while using PDF X-Change Standard for printing a document. 
[JunkCharPrintedInPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Op62.png)

```
graphics.DrawString(string.Concat("\u202A", dString), pFont, pBrush new Rectangle(x + (width - dStringWidth), y + (2 * lHeight), dtringWidth, lHeight), sfHeader);
```

Kindly suggest a solution for this issue

I tried using various other embedding characters, string formatting etc but nothing is working properly.

Comment: Care to share the code?

Comment: Adding a sample code for ref. @Christie TIA.
`graphics.DrawString(string.Concat("\u202A", dString), pFont, pBrush
                                        new Rectangle(x + (width - dStringWidth), y + (2 * lHeight), dtringWidth, lHeight),
                                        sfHeader);`

Comment: What is the library you're using?

Comment: System.Drawing, System.Drawing.Imaging, System.Drawing.Printing